# SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. ERROR?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, version

I have downloaded Xcode today from the App Store, it is version 11.4.

When I run xcrun swift -version in Terminal I get: 
Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0

In Xcode, I have gone to Build Settings -> Swift Language Version and changed it to Swift 5.

Then when I try to build my code I get this error message: 
SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0.

I have no idea what I need to do, this is the first time I have ever used Mac or Xcode

Comment: Edit your question with the steps you took to create the project and any third party libraries you're using. Creating a brand new iOS app project with Xcode 11.4 should give you Swift 5, not Swift 3.

Comment: Did you use cocoapod for dependency management ?